# Add multiple "types" to a submit button in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a submit button on a form that is an image, and I want it to clear the form once it is clicked.

To make the submit button an image, I use the following code:

```
<%= f.submit "2", :type => :image, :src => "/assets/down.png" %>
```

To make the button clear the form, I use the following code

```
<%= f.submit "2", :type => :reset %>
```

But I have tried and failed to add two "types" to the form

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use javascript here (to submit your form after pressing on your image (or as you want -- reset it).

```
$('#form').trigger("reset");
```

Comment: This is my backup plan in case I can't manage to make it happen within the form_for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.

By default, the `form_for` `submit` *must* **and** *will* be an HTML tag `<input type="submit" />`. Without the `type` attribute being set to `"submit"`, the tag wouldn't actually be a submit button and would certainly not be able to submit the form without some sort of client-side intercession (e.g., Javascript).

CORRECTION:

The OP is correct that `"image"` *is* indeed a valid `type` attribute for [an image button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1).

Comment: em...I might not be understanding something here. the two pieces of code I added on the question work! They generate the following html code: `<input type="image" value="2" src="/assets/down.png" name="commit">` and 
`<input type="reset" value="2" name="commit">`. What I can't find how to do is how to add both at the same time. Apologies if I didn't make myself clear

Comment: Do you mean you want both `type="image"` and `type="reset"` within the same single `<input>` tag?

Comment: Exactly. If possible. Otherwise I'll go javascript like the other solution suggested it.